# Kerning bug with Verdana in Firefox and Chrome at 15 pixels

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, fonts, typography

I noticed a kerning issue with Verdana at 15 pixels in Firefox and Chrome on Windows.  See the image below and note the extra space between the "o" and the "r". This image is a screenshot from Chrome with only font-famliy and font-size styles applied to the paragraphs.

Does that mean that there's a bug in the kerning table for the Open Type version of the font? Where would I even report a bug like that?

[image]

Comment: The first thing to do would be to do a test with the same word in the same font, displayed by some other program, to help determine whether the bug is in the font or Firefox. Once you've done that, if you have more questions, you probably want to ask some place like [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), where it's more likely to be topical.

Comment: I did test in Internet Explorer and it displayed fine (thus my guess that it's the Open Type version verus the True Type that's broken). I'll ask on SuperUser as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's a system issue in Windows.
On Windows 7, Notepad, set font to Verdana, size 11.

This results in broken metrics/kerning:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could try to put *-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased* in your css, here you have the explanation http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing

Comment: I forget, try also to work in em instead of pixel, if you need here you have a converter http://pxtoem.com/

Comment: Sorry, but neither anti-aliasing nor px vs em has anything to do with this issue.

Comment: Hi again alexp. Did you try with text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; http://www.aestheticallyloyal.com/public/optimize-legibility/ ?